# Is there an automatic, more efficient and fast way to export all modules?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Here is my `CampaignService` module.

[image]

Now, I want to re-export all modules in `index.ts`, like this:

```js
export * from './ApiError';
export * from './Budget';
//...
```

As you can see, there are a lot of modules, is there an automatic, more efficient and fast way to export these modules? I don't want to re-export them one by one manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this may be a little hard to explain. Wish I could give a video or something.

But this trick is awesome.

1. **Select all the module files for export**. Right click and copy the relative path.
   [image: first]
2. Open new blank file and paste all. Also hit `F1` and `change language mode` to `Javascript react`. This part is for hinting only. Not mandatory.
   [image: second A][image: second 2]
3. Now the tricky part. Go to start of the file and use Multi cursor. For me it was `Alt + Shift + Direction key`. If you don't know then search in settings for multicursor. Now I have a cursor on each line beginning.
   [image: third]
4. Now type the common part for each line. Here `export * from` and you can select next word in each line with `Ctrl + right`.

### [image: fourth]

**EDIT:**

Something better. If you don't want to make multicursor then

Hit `Ctrl F` to find the common thing you want to remove in each line. Here in my screenshot it would be `assets`. And hit `alt enter`(or whatever your multicursor modifier in settings. Now you have multicursor with selected word.